# Appednding the text on a TextInput field to list in kivy for manipulation

Tags: python, android, list, kivy, textinput

- **Appending TextInput objects to a list.**

I created a screen with buttons 0 - 9 with a single TextInput field that displays the numbers on_clicking them, along with an **ENTER** button.

- Assuming I clicked **5 & 6** , 56 will be displayed on the TextInput field.
- what I'm trying to achieve is: on_clicking the ***ENTER*** button, the number displaying on the TextInput field should be added to a list for manipulation.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a functiun to a `TextInput`, by using `on_text_validate`. If you use this, a certain function will run, when the user hits Enter. Here is how it should look in the `kv` file:

```
TextInput:
    id: mytext
    on_text_validate: root.add_to_list()
```

And then in the `py` file in the class:

```
class YourApp(FloatLayout): #FloatLayout is just an example, you can use this method with all layouts
    list = []
    def add_to_list(self):
        content_of_textfield = self.ids.mytext.text
#saving the content of the textfield into a variable
        list.append(content_of_textfield) #adding the variable to the list
```